# deriving Dialogs from a custom Dialog using mfc

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, dialog, icons

I am trying to define a custom Dialog Template with certain members such as `m_hImage`, `m_hName`, and the `m_hIcon` in it. I want to then derive Dialogs using this Template.

I am not using any buttons(Ok,cancel etc.) in this template. Do i still need to declare or define `OnOk()`, `OnCancel()` etc.

Can anybody tell me what are the other methods I need to declare in this template class?

My goal is to just prepare this template dialog so that each dialog derived from this template contains a icon on the title bar (`m_hIcon`) , the image (`m_hImage`) on the upper left corner, and the image name (`m_hName`) on the upper right corner of dialog.

Answer (score 1):

No, you need not to override any of the methods. You may however need to override `OnInitDialog`, otherwise you won't have any dialog initialization. This is the overridden method where you can setup the icon for dialog.